# (Tricky) Call method from app.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, methods, call

I have a Pivot-Page App, which has different app-bars for each different page.
The methods from the app-bar are all declared in app.xaml.cs but all the input-elements are on MainPage.xaml.cs.

I have a login button on one of my app-bars, but in the app.xaml.cs I have no access to textboxes etc.

Creating a new instance of MainPage isn't helping, because all textbox values would be empty.
Yes, my method in MainPage is public, but `MainPage.method();` doesn't work.

How can I call a method in MainPage.xaml.cs, which uses MainPage's textboxes, from app.xaml.cs?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to put GUI elements in app.xaml.cs

Comment: I had to declare my different app-bars in app.xaml.cs. Therefore, each method of those app-bar is in app.xaml.cs.

Comment: What do you mean by maethod() doesn't work? Are you trying in App class call this.MainWindow.method() ? Is the right page set? Do you call it after is constructed?

Answer (score 2):

```
((MainPage)App.Current.RootVisual).method()
```

Answer (score 1):

I went brute force: I made my app bar by hand in the class I wanted to make it.
**And it works**.

[I got the tip from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431786%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic how to based on the code I needed for an app I am writing:

In MainPage.xaml you create a method as follows:

```
public static void InMainPage()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hi I am a method in MainPage.xaml.cs");
}
```

Now in App.xaml.cs you can now reference it in any method as such:

```
MainPage.InMainPage();
```

Hope this answer helps you or someone else in the same predicament